Backup gives me this msg "Waiting for 999 gb volume to become connected". Disc utility sees it. Files doesn't
Disks says it is /dev/sdb ... partitioning is "Master Boot Record" It had Ubuntu 24.04 image in the first partition. I deleted that.
